# Composer was unable to install the updates. Error: Unknown package has no name defined

Tags: craft3, updates, composer

Hi I cannot install Craft CMS updates. I have version 3.1.18 and I'm trying to update to 3.7.50

I have updated Composer successfully. I did however have a platform PHP 7 issue listed in composer.json which was overriding the server version required for the update. I wish I had just manually removed the line from the file to see if that would have fixed it but instead followed an instruction on github to use command: `composer config platform --unset` this didn't work when I then tried to update but I had noticed terminal that the response from the --unset request was that some plugins were skipped and that I should use command `composer update --no-plugins` which I tried.

From now on when I try to run the Craft update I get the error:

`Composer was unable to install the updates. Error: Unknown package has no name defined` then proceeds to list the plugins. I cannot uninstall any plugins either to see if that would help. I have followed the advice on this post:

["Error: Unknown package has no name defined" when updating Craft 3](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/36605/error-unknown-package-has-no-name-defined-when-updating-craft-3)

I couldn't delete the vendor folder as suggested in that post as access is denied for some reason but I could rename it. It still doesn't work though and I still get the same error when trying to update Craft.

This is the full composer.json file:

```
{
  "require": {
    "adigital/cookie-consent-banner": "1.2.9",
    "craftcms/cms": "3.1.18",
    "craftcms/redactor": "2.3.3.2",
    "dolphiq/redirect": "1.1.1",
    "vlucas/phpdotenv": "^2.4.0"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "modules\\": "modules/"
    }
  },
  "config": {
    "sort-packages": true,
    "optimize-autoloader": true,
    "allow-plugins": {
      "yiisoft/yii2-composer": true,
      "craftcms/plugin-installer": true
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
      "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ]
  }
}
```

I have searched other solutions but have now arrived at a dead end.

What am I missing please?

Comment: Please post the full content of your `composer.json` file.

Comment: Ok I've added the full composer.json file.

Comment: Try to delete the composer.lock as well as the vendor folder. Then install the most up-to-date version of Composer and use composer update. Don't use --no-plugins, the Composer plugins are required to make sure plugins are installed correctly in the right place.

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work. I couldn't delete the vendor folder but could rename it and I deleted composer.lock, then ran composer install and composer update. This generated a new vendor folder and new composer.lock file but still get the same error when I try to run the craft update.

Comment: I got on to server support and they changed permissions so I can delete vendor folders now but still keep hitting the same error. If I run composer install will this install the most up to date version or should I specify a version number to install?

Comment: If you run `composer install` after deleting the `vendor` folder and the `composer.lock` file, Composer will download the newest versions of all dependencies that are listed in your `composer.json`, accoring to your version constraints. For example, `"craftcms/cms": "3.1.18"` means you get the newest Craft 3.x.x version, but not Craft 4.

Comment: Yes I'm not after craft 4 but want the newest craft 3x yet still I get the same error. Is there anything else you can think of that might work?

Comment: Ah I see you have fixed version constraint, so `composer install` / `composer update` can only ever install those exact versions. I'll write up an answer that should solve this.

Answer (score 1):

You have fixed version constraints in your `composer.json`, so `composer install` and `composer update` will only ever install those exact versions.  In general, you should use the `update/all` console command to update Craft and any installed plugins, as this will also execute any pending migrations. The error you're getting is unrelated to this and is likely only a compatibility issue between different composer versions.

To fix this, follow the following steps to first get back to a clean composer install and then use the console to update to Craft 3.7. You should do this in a development environment where you have control over your environment and can go back to a previous version easily if something goes wrong.

1. Delete the `vendor` folder and the `composer.lock` file.
2. Execute `composer install`. If you're getting any errors regarding version conflicts, change the version requirements for the installed packages to compatible versions.

Once the installation goes through cleanly, use `php craft update/all` to update to the latest Craft 3.7 version. See the [update guide](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/updating.html#updating-from-the-terminal) for details.

Comment: One note: you shouldn't mix using `composer update` and `craft update/all` because of how Craft pins your versions in `composer.json`. Pick one way and always use it. I like `composer update`, followed by `craft migrate/all`.

Comment: @CraftQuest With a standard install based on the starter project, `composer update` will not update Craft or any plugins though, since the version constraints are pinned to exact versions. Same goes if you've previously used `php craft update all`, since that command pins specific versions as well. I like having fixed versions for Craft and plugins and using `php craft update all`, because it performs migrations in the same step. This way, I can use `composer update` to update all packages _except_ Craft and plugins and I can be sure I'm not missing any migrations.

Comment: After installing the website locally and getting it to work (which was fun). I followed the instructions, I deleted the vendor folder and composer.lock, ran composer install (no errors), ran php craft update all, it said performing 1 update : - craft 3.1.18 => 3.7.50 (CRITICAL), all good then ran it and same error: error: Unknown package has no name defined ([{"name":"adigital\/cookie-consent-banner".... so still not working!

Comment: Update: I followed these instructions and it generated a different error. However when I tried to log back in it gave me the option to upgrade the database and once that happened everything was up to date: https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/36551/unknown-package-has-no-name-defined-composer-error-on-upgrade